# I can click on the images, but why can't I see them? (M1 mac, Java)

Tags: java

```
package Dynamic_Beat;

public class DynamicBeat extends JFrame {

    private Image screenImage;
    private Graphics screenGraphic;

    private ImageIcon startButtonBasicImage = new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("../images/START_Basic.png"));
    private ImageIcon startButtonEnteredImage = new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("../images/START_Entered.png"));

    private Image background = new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("../images/Rhythm_power.png")).getImage();
    private JLabel menuBar = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("../images/menuBar.png")));

    private JButton startButton = new JButton(startButtonBasicImage);

    private int mouseX, mouseY;

    public DynamicBeat() {
        setUndecorated(true);
        setTitle("Dynamic Beat");
        setSize(Main.SCREEN_WIDTH, Main.SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        setLayout(null);

        startButton.setBounds(40, 200, 400, 100);
        startButton.setBorderPainted(false);
        startButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        startButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        startButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                startButton.setIcon(startButtonEnteredImage);
                startButton.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
                startButton.setIcon(startButtonBasicImage);
                startButton.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
            }
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                Music buttonEnteredMusic = new Music("buttonPressedMusic.wav", false);
                buttonEnteredMusic.start();
                startButton.setVisible(false);
                quitButton.setVisible(false);
            }

        });
        add(startButton);

        menuBar.setBounds(0, 0, 1280, 30);
        menuBar.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                mouseX = e.getX();
                mouseY = e.getY();
            }
        });
        menuBar.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                int x = e.getXOnScreen();
                int y = e.getYOnScreen();
                setLocation(x - mouseX, y - mouseY);
            }
        });
        add(menuBar);

        Music introMusic = new Music("intro_music.mp3", true);
        introMusic.start();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        screenImage = createImage(Main.SCREEN_WIDTH, Main.SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        screenGraphic = screenImage.getGraphics();
        screenDraw(screenGraphic);
        g.drawImage(background, 0,0,null);
    }

    public void screenDraw(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
        paintComponents(g);
        this.repaint();
    }

}
```

I'm using M1 mac. We are working on a mini project to make simple games at IntelliJ with java.

There was no problem with setting the size, inserting the right background picture, and adding music.
And I tried to make the game start button and click the button to move on to the main screen. But I can't see the game start button itself. However, when you put the mouse on it, the cursor changes and recognizes it well and moves on to the main screen. But I can't see the image of the button itself.
What's wrong with me?

please help.

Comment: Are you certain the image for the button is loaded properly?

Comment: yeap 100% sure, bcuz i can click them